# TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'items.filter') in react native

Tags: react-native, autocomplete

Why I am getting that error `TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'items.filter')` when using `react-native-dropdown-autocomplete` in my react native app?
I am getting data from fetch method and store that data in arrayholder

My code is like that

```
<Autocomplete
  style={styles.input}
  scrollToInput={ev => {}}
  keyExtractor={(item, index) => index + ""}
  handleSelectItem={(item, id) => this.handleSelectItem(item, id)}
  onDropdownClose={() => onDropdownClose()}
  onDropdownShow={() => onDropdownShow()}
  onChangeText={(text) => this.searchFilterFunction(text)}
  data={this.state.data}
  minimumCharactersCount={0}
  highlightText
  valueExtractor={item => item.name}
  rightContent
/>

searchFilterFunction = (text) => {
  this.setState({
  value: text,
  });
  
  const newData = this.arrayholder.filter(item => {     
    const itemData = `${item.name.toUpperCase()}`;
    const textData = text.toUpperCase();
    return itemData.indexOf(textData) > -1;
  });
  this.setState({ data: newData });
};
```

Comment: `items` will be undefined if `this.state.data` is undefined. Be sure it's at least an empty array.

Comment: You said *store that data in arrayholder*. Where are you doing this?